# How can I fetch data on every app start using nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I have a blog application created in nextjs. I want to fetch menus (nav) from the api and load to Nav component. But how can I fetch menus on every refresh and save it to react context api? I have tried fetch menus from home page and save it to react context api, but on other pages menus are not available.

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient());

  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <ReactQueryDevtools />
        </Hydrate>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </AppProvider>
  );
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  const response= await apiClient().get('/api/index');

  const { setMenus } = useAppContext(); // This line not working
  setMenus(response.data);

  return { ...appProps };
};
```

Comment: In your example, YOU DON'T NEED CONTEXT since you drilled the props to every `Component` through `pageProps`, your response already on every entry page props. Use the response to pass in addition to `{...appProps, menus: response.data}`

Comment: @DennisVash Then, how can I access menus from other components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your stragedy here, but you can go either way, pass the menu to your provider or use the drilled props:

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  // OR pass those menus to the provider
  const {menus} = pageProps;


  // OR the response already passed to every page entry point at pageProps
  return (
    <AppProvider value={menus}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AppProvider>
  );
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  const response= await apiClient().get('/api/index');
  return { ...appProps, menus: response.data };
};

// Now from every entry page like MenuPage, the menu should be available OR use it as context consumer
const MenuPage = ({menu}) => {...}
```

Comment: Then, how can I access menus from other components?

Comment: To which of the methods you refer to? Also I mentioned it in the answer

Comment: Thank you. Last question, is this a best way to load menus to navigation that are dynamic?

Comment: Sounds reasonable solution, "best way" is opinionated.

Comment: I tried to get menus from component but it undefined?